# Browser Extension: How to execute a function when an element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am working on a browser extension.
It has two parts:

1. popup - which contains checkboxes
2. content script - which contains the code to alter the CSS property

I am saving the states of checkboxes so that the next time I open the popup again the same checkboxes are marked as checked.
When I use the checkboxes they change the DOM as intended, however when I try to alter the DOM after the page is loaded, changes are not reflected. This is probably because the element on which I want to perform the operation is loaded slow and thus required operations fail.

I tried to use onload and ready but nothing worked

```js
$('.question-list-table').on('load', function() {
    browser.storage.local.get(["options"], modifyThenApplyChanges)
});
```

I also tried, but nothing changed.

```js
$('body').on('load','.question-list-table', function() {
    browser.storage.local.get(["options"], modifyThenApplyChanges)
});
```

Also, there is no visible error with the popup or content script as I test in both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

**Update:**

As suspected earlier, the target element is loaded slowly so I used `setTimeout` for `5 seconds` and the script is working as intended.

Loading time is variable and I want to show my changes as early as possible everything in a consistent manner.

Comment: Load event doesn't exist for most elements. Only for a few like `<iframe>` and `<img>` as well as `window`. If the script that opens the popup has an events api you could try using that or use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Can you try putting all your code in a jsfiddle like this one?  http://jsfiddle.net/Lwxoeyyp/1/

Comment: @charlietfl popup is created using a browser action and only Content Script has access to DOM elements. I try to solve my problem using Mutation Observer

Comment: @FSDford This extension has various scripts and my question is depended upon the website and the necessary code in order to keep my question short and to the point is already mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through `MutationObserver` as suggested by @charlietfl in the comment section, this is what I coded and works for me

```js
// Mutation Observer
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if(mutation.addedNodes.length) {
           //do stuff
        }
    });
});

el = document.getElementsById('elementId');
if(el) {
    observer.observe(el, {
        childList: true // specify the kind of change you are looking for
    });
}
```